# Getting "Site unavailable" when exporting reports to PDF or CSV

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, reporting-services, windows-server-2008

I've deployed a web application on IIS 7.0 running on windows server 2008 r2. We have some reports in this web application. Everything is working fine in the web application, except when I try to export reports to PDF or CSV. This shows the following message:

> Unable to open this Internet site.
>   The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.
>   Please try again later.

This message comes only on IE8, the issue is not showing in Mozilla Firefox. I don't know where this issue is coming from or how to solve this issue.

Comment: What do the IIS logs say? The failed request should be available with more information.

Comment: I am not able to understand that what IIS log says. Do I need to post IIS log on here?

Comment: Not the whole log. Just the lines that pertain to the failed request.

Comment: I resolved this issue. This issue occurs because I had written code in global.asax that not to store cache.

Comment: Good to hear you solved the issue. It's helpful if you convert that comment into a (if possible somewhat more substantial) answer to your own question, making it easier for others with this problem to spot the solution.